# Android Facebook graph api, JSONException No value for photos

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get a list of the users photos from the Facebook graph api but I keep getting the error:

```
JSONException No value for photos
```

I have searched through every other answer available, and tried all of the suggestions but I have not been able to find what is causing the error.

This is the function I have been using to get the photos:

```
public void getUserPhotos(){
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONObject object,
                            GraphResponse response) {
                        try {
                            //This contains all the photos with array data>>link
                            JSONObject photosobject = object.getJSONObject("photos");

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "photos{link}");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }
```

I created a test user and ensured they have correct permissions. It is logging in fine and I can get the users public info.

I thought it might be a permission issue so I ran this:

```
String permissions = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions().toString();
System.out.println(permissions);
```

The response logged was:

```
[public_profile, user_friends, user_photos]
```

So it is not a permission issue.

I logged into the user and added photos so that shouldn't be the issue either.

I have seen some example use `"photos{link}"` as the field and others use `"images"`.

`"photos{link}"` gives me this error:

```
12-28 22:34:23.991 9199-9199/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for photos
12-28 22:34:23.991 9199-9199/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
12-28 22:34:23.991 9199-9199/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:609)
12-28 22:34:23.991 9199-9199/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:     at com.mysampleapp.Fragments.ProfileFragment$1.onCompleted(ProfileFragment.java:294)
12-28 22:34:23.991 9199-9199/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:     at com.facebook.GraphRequest$1.onCompleted(GraphRequest.java:304)
12-28 22:34:23.991 9199-9199/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:     at com.facebook.GraphRequest$5.run(GraphRequest.java:1368)
12-28 22:34:23.991 9199-9199/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
12-28 22:34:23.992 9199-9199/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-28 22:34:23.992 9199-9199/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
12-28 22:34:23.992 9199-9199/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
12-28 22:34:23.992 9199-9199/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-28 22:34:23.992 9199-9199/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
12-28 22:34:23.992 9199-9199/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

The `"images"` field just returns a null pointer exception.

I looked over the grapi api documentation and found this:

> The /me node is a special endpoint that translates to the user_id of
>   the person (or the page_id of the Facebook Page) whose access token is
>   currently being used to make the API calls. If you had a user access
>   token, you could retrieve all of a user's photos by using:
>
> GET graph.facebook.com   /me/photos

This seems correct and I am running a me request, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the content of the returned JSONObject (try logging object.toString())?

Comment: Hi, The object came back as {"id":"106121596557455"}

Comment: The response came back as {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"id":"106121596557455"}, error: null}

Answer (score 1):

mainActivity.java

```
   btnLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.v("Main", response.toString());
                            setProfileToView(object);
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }


 public void showCustomDialog(JSONObject jsonObject)
{
     final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.facebookdetails);
    dialog.setTitle("Facebook Details");
    email = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.email);
    facebookName = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.name);
    gender = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.gender);
    infoLayout = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.layout_info);
    profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView)dialog. findViewById(R.id.imageprofile);
    DateofBirth= (TextView)dialog. findViewById(R.id.dob);
    showProgressDialog();
    try {
        disconnectFromFacebook();
        if(jsonObject.has("birthday"))
        {
            DateofBirth.setText(jsonObject.getString("birthday"));

        }
        if(jsonObject.has("email")){
            email.setText(jsonObject.getString("email"));

        }
        if(jsonObject.has("gender")||jsonObject.has("name")) {
            gender.setText(jsonObject.getString("gender"));
            facebookName.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));
        }
        profilePictureView.setPresetSize(ProfilePictureView.NORMAL);
        profilePictureView.setProfileId(jsonObject.getString("id"));
        infoLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    dialog.show();
    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
```